# system of equations which share only one variable?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am trying to build a website that runs on this equation. I know how to solve the equation for two variables that are in both equations but I have no idea how to solve for three variables where the two equations only have one in common. I am only in pre-algebra so if you can answer in a way that i can understand that would be great.

Here is the system of equations:

$10,000=mx+5000$

$y=1000x$

Comment: there are three variables,$x,y,m$?

Comment: yes there are. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

*Two* equations for *three* unknowns should ring a bell... And indeed one cannot deduce $(x,y,m)$ from the two equations in your post. The most one can do is to write two of them as explicit functions of the third one.